# How to limit the number of concurrently processed tasks when using Apache Pulsar as a distributed task queue?

Tags: distributed, task-queue, apache-pulsar

I am currently evaluating the suitability of Apache Pulsar to build a distributed task queue using a "shared" subscription.

One required feature is to limit the number of concurrently processed tasks for certain topics.
By this I mean the sum of all messages for a given subscription that have been received by consumers but are not yet acknowledged.
Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: How about using the consumers as your parallel tasks limit, thus limit the number of consumers, with an assumption each consumer is working on one message concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

well, you are in charge of coding and deploying your consumers. For example, if a topic has 10 consumers and each consumer processes 5 messages in parallel, then you will never have more than 50 concurrently processed messages.